# jQuery show first child not working corectly

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I'm using jQuery to hide some elements on my page, this works fine and I can slide toggle between the elements. However I want the first child to be shown, however this isn't working correctly. I've used the same code before so I dont understand why it doesnt work.

I basically want the first togglesettings div to be shown on the page load and the rest to be hidden.

My code is below or view my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7nEP/):

index.html

```
<div class="container maincontent add-top add-bottom">

<div class="container add-top">
    <h3>Welcome John Doe</h3>
    <p>Please select which service you would like to manage below</p>
    <hr />
</div>

<div class="blockwrapper">
<div class="container editblocks">
    <div class="editblock block_item_1">
    <h3 class="showpageblock">Page Settings</h3>
        <div class="togglesettings">
            <div class="form-group two-thirds column">
                <label class="form-label">Filename: </label> <input class="edit-page-input" type="text"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group two-thirds column">
                <label class="form-label">Navigation button (words): </label> <input class="edit-page-input" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End Toggle Settings -->
    </div><!-- End Block -->
</div> <!-- End Edit Block -->

<div class="container editblocks">
    <div class="editblock block_item_2">
        <h3 class="showpageblock">SEO</h3>
            <div class="togglesettings">
                <p>Loreum Ipsum</p>
            </div><!-- End Toggle Settings -->
        </div><!-- End Block -->
</div> <!-- End Block -->

<div class="container editblocks">
    <div class="editblock block_item_2">
        <h3 class="showpageblock">SEO</h3>
            <div class="togglesettings">
                <p>Loreum Ipsum</p>
            </div><!-- End Toggle Settings -->
        </div><!-- End Block -->
</div> <!-- End Block -->
</div>

</div> <!-- End Main Content Div -->
```

Js/js.js

```
$('.togglesettings').hide();
$('.togglesettings:first-child').show;
$('.showpageblock').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.editblocks').siblings().find('.togglesettings').slideUp();
            $(this).next('.togglesettings').slideToggle();
            $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
    return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, why the `first-child` selector does not work, but you can use `.first()` as workaround:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/julian_weinert/C7nEP/3/)

```
$('.togglesettings').hide();
$('.togglesettings').first().show();
$('.showpageblock').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.editblocks').siblings().find('.togglesettings').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.togglesettings').slideToggle();
    $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
 $('.togglesettings').hide();
 $('.togglesettings:first').show();
 $('.showpageblock').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.editblocks').siblings().find('.togglesettings').slideUp();
            $(this).next('.togglesettings').slideToggle();
            $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
    return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parenthesis `()`

```
$('.togglesettings:first-child').show; // use show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code can help you.

```
$('.togglesettings').hide();
$('.blockwrapper .container:first-child').find('.togglesettings').show()
$('.showpageblock').on('click', function () {
    $('.togglesettings').hide();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Update fiddle link is here: http://jsfiddle.net/C7nEP/4/

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you're expecting ":first-child" to look for the first instance of ".togglesettings". However, what it really does is look for is the first child of its **parent** - which in your case is the ".showpageblock" DIV.

As the solutions provided by others suggest, use ".first()" instead. It's not a CSS selector, but a jQuery method that searches through the DOM for the first one in the whole tree.

[jQuery API - :first-child](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

[jQuery API - .first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)